# How to auto open Infowindow on marker on NgMap load?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

How to auto open infowindow on marker on NgMap load ?

Here is my code:

```
<map  center="{{lat}},{{lng}}"   zoom="10" >
   <marker id="mymarker" position="{{lat}},{{lng}}"></marker>
   <info-window id="bar"> <b>Hello World!</b></info-window>
</map>
```

Any `onload` events to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an idea for you to tailor it to your problem // review the example

NgMap.getMap({id:"map"}) -> Returns a promise, and the function then executes the code after that map is loaded

```
angular.module('ngMap').controller('MyCtrl', function(NgMap) {
  NgMap.getMap({id:"map"}).then(function(map) {       
    map.showInfoWindow('bar', 'marker1');
  });
});
```

```html
<ng-map id="map" default-style="true" center="-25.363882,131.044922" zoom="4">
      <marker id="marker1" position="-25.363882,131.044922"
        on-click="map.showInfoWindow('bar')">
      </marker>
      <info-window id="bar">
        <div ng-non-bindable>
          Bla bla
        </div>
      </info-window>
</ng-map>
```

> [Example plunk AutoLoad infowindow](http://plnkr.co/edit/fIjL6E3zLVAkUY4i1fCP?p=preview)